# The Event Horizon Telescope collaboration will announce groundbreaking observations of our galaxy at 12 May 2022, what this announcement could be?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, telescopes, radiometry

> "Live webcasting for the ESO-hosted EHT 2022 event
>
> On 12 May 2022 at 15:00 CEST, the European Southern Observatory (ESO) will host a press conference on groundbreaking new Milky Way results from the Event Horizon Telescope Collaboration (EHT). You can watch the press conference live on this page, or on ESO's YouTube channel."

https://www.eso.org/public/live/

**What this announcement could be?**